# I require help to find a good data source for my thesis

Tags: historical-data, statistical-finance, fundamentals, data-source

I require help to find a good data source for my master thesis.

I am doing a regression analysis for macroeconomic indicators and valuation multiples, for eurozone stocks.

I need quarterly information about valuation ratios like P/E P/B P/OFC etc. For preferably 1000 companies over a minimum of 10 years.

Preferable structured in CSV style table:

#name     #Date    #P/E #P/B

#Bayer AG #q1/2000 #8,3 #2

#Bayer AG #q2/2019 #8,5 #2,2

#Air France SE #q1/2000 #5,5 #1,3

#Air France SE #q4/2019 #4,5 #1,2

Budget: less than 500€

At the moment I use finbox.com which allows the manual download of quarterly valuation ratios.
The issue with finbox.com is that it is a manual download of an excel sheet per single company, limited by the last 10 years, with no information if it starts 2010 or 2011.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It would help if you elaborated on how you searched and what you found, and also what languages/tools you have access to. Surely you googled a bit, didn't you? Eg a quick google search brings up some Python code to retrieve PE ratios from yahoo Finance https://algotrading101.com/learn/yahoo-finance-api-guide/#Price-to-Earnings-Ratio   or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60428931/how-can-i-using-yfinance-to-get-fundamental-ratios-such-as-p-e-p-b

Comment: Commonly, your uni should have access to either a Reuters Eikon/Datastream terminal or to Bloomberg, or to some other financial database. These can be queried quite easily (step 1: list all companies that fall into your pattern, step 2: get all data for this list), and are usually of high quality.

Comment: Yahoo finance API can only load single stock data for specific moment. Not bulk data. I need bulk data for many companies for a long time.

Comment: My Uni has no access to Reuters Eikon/Datastream terminal or to Bloomberg or any other terminal that provides such data.